# Multiple Child selector in on() Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the on() method in jquery and I want to know if it's possible to shorten my code because I am just using the code over and over again but with different child selectors. **Is it possible to use multiple child selectors in one `on()`?**

This is a sample code and I have a lot of code like this.

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name*="create"]', function() {
  var $class = $(this).attr('class');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { //not checked
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': false
    });
  } else {
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': true
    });
  }
});

$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name*="compute"]', function() {
  var $class = $(this).attr('class');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { //not checked
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': false
    });
  } else {
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': true
    });
  }
});

$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name*="print"]', function() {
  var $class = $(this).attr('class');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { //not checked
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': false
    });
  } else {
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': true
    });
  }
});
```

I want to know if it's possible to use multiple `'input[name*="create"]'` in one `on()` so that I won't have to repeat it.

Comment: Why not just create a function that you call instead of duplicating the anonymous function 3 times?

Comment: `'input[name*="create"], input[name*="compute"], input[name*="print"]'`, or better yet, use a class.

Comment: `$class` is a string, not a `$` jQuery Object reference, so use `klass` :)

Comment: those inputs are on multiple checkboxes for example   `{!! Form::checkbox('quality_control_create', '1', null, array('class' => 'quality_control')) !!}Create CA`

Comment: There is more space to remove duplication. For example you could replace if statement with `$('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({'checked':$(this).is(':checked')})`

Comment: Can you just show a HTML sample? (So I can see the actual classNames)

Comment: Again, can you please show your full `$class` classNames? Because targeting other elements using `*=`+some classname is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: it's always something different but above the `$class` name will be `array('class' => 'quality_control')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name*="create"],input[name*="print"], input[name*="compute"]', function () {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the same function lines in multiple places, declare it to a single function name at first. Then you can call it whenever you need it.

For the implementing part, you can implement one event to multiple classes with css selector. (below)

```js
function dotheAction(e) {
  var $class = $(e).attr('class');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { //not checked
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': false
    });
  } else {
    $('input[name*="' + $class + '_selectall"]').attr({
      'checked': true
    });
  }
};

$(document.body).on('change', 'input[name*="create"], input[name*="compute"], input[name*="print"]', dotheAction(this));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never** target-reference other elements by using the caller's `className`. One day you'll add a styling class to your element and your JS will break and let you wondering.

**Instead** Use `data-*` attribute to reference:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-target="create"> Create<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="compute"> Compute <br>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="print"> Print<br>
```

considering that the i.e: *create* above will target all

```
<input type="checkbox" name="create_selectall">
```

elements, than this is all you need.
*Really*.

```
$("body").on('change', 'input[data-target]', function() {
  $('input[name*="'+ this.dataset.target +'_selectall"]').prop({checked: !this.checked});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can event create a function that attaches event to elements in the dom and applies a the wanted callback.

```js
   function attachEvent(eventName, selector, callback) {
        $(document).on(eventName, selector, callback);
    }

    var changeCallback = function () {
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            
            console.info(className);
            
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { //not checked
                $('input[name*="' + className + '_selectall"]').attr({
                    'checked': false
                });
            } else {
                $('input[name*="' + className + '_selectall"]').attr({
                    'checked': true
                });
            }
        };

    attachEvent('change', 'input[name*="create"],input[name*="compute"],input[name*="print"]', changeCallback);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="create" class="create" placeholder="create" type="text" />
<input name="compute" class="compute" placeholder="compute" type="text" />
<input name="print" class="print" placeholder="print" type="text" />
```

Comment: Humm... You're just creating an additional layer of complexity. `$("sel").on("change", "dyn", cb);` is quite enough, clear, simple, tells what it does - without the need to go lookup to some globally polluted `attachEvent` function variable.